# Computing dilogarithm

Tags: finite-element, integration, approximation, comsol, integral-equations

I'm measuring the integral of a quantity which, mathematically, requires the computation of a dilogarithm function.

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(be^{ax})$$

where $b$ and $a$ (are real and) can be positive or negative. Dilogarithm has very nice properties that enable us to compute its value efficiently, For $|z|<1$, the following series converges absolutely:

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$

I'm wondering is there any explicit way to compute or numerically approximate dilogarithm -- especially in COMSOL?

Comment: See Fullerton's dspenc.for from  http://www.netlib.org/fn/ function  or the GSL routine
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#dilogarithm

Comment: @gammatester Thanks, let me check. I'll get back to you.

Comment: You could also check out mpmath's implementation: https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/d011c94abc5586bf685fac29e22605dc4e5bc7bf/mpmath/functions/zeta.py#L463